# tone() library calls fails on alternating tones

Tags: arduino

I have a Leonardo generating a square wave using tone().  I ran the output through an LC low pass filter and fed into into a recording jack.  Everything works fine for one continuous tone.  But if I try and vary the frequency, for example:

```
loop()
{
   tone(8,1300);
   delay(10);
   tone(8,1500);
   delay(10);
}
```

then every now and again (it varies, e.g. 14ms, 28ms, 71ms) the signal disappears for about 4ms.  This happens even when no other code apart from the above is present, i.e. no serial port access etc.

How can I get the Leonardo to generate tones without these gaps appearing?[image]

Comment: PS: Using noTone() makes no difference

Comment: Hi Peter, I've just had a look at the source for the Tone library. When you pass a duration, it calculates a "toggleCount", which controls how many times the timer counters should be reset. It uses an Interrupt Service Routine to decrement and check this count. My guess is that the delay() function, which you use, is interfering with this somehow. Delay() is quite nasty on Arduino, involving a very tight loop which keeps the AVY pretty much 100% busy. The Delay() docmentation does state that ISRs won't be affected, but I would say this is your problem.

Comment: Might be worth having a look at http://code.google.com/p/arduino-softtimer/

Comment: Thanks Greycon.  That could be true... but it doesn't make sense that it could cause a 4000 microsecond 'silence' as described above.  Surely that is waaay too long for a bit of ISR interference?

Comment: Hmm, OK. Just for pig-iron, how about replacing the delay() with one of the Timer() classes, and seeing if it helps?

Comment: have you tried it with out the USB connected. Just a thought it may be the USB ISR

Comment: Good suggestion mpflaga. Yes I did try that once, same issue.  Perhaps the USB routines are messing with Timer2, even when disconnected?